# TYPO3 9.5 second database - Errors in ExtensionManager

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a problem when adding a second third party Oracle database to the TYPO3 Configuration in a TYPO3 9.5. After adding the configuration I cannot install any extensions (including core extensions) in ExtensionManager anymore.

In LocalConfiguration.php I add a second database (it's the database of a patent management system - no "TYPO3 style"):

```
'DB' => [
  'Connections' => [
    'Default' => [
      ....
    ],
    'MyDB' => [
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'dbname' => 'xxx',
      'driver' => 'oci8',
      'host' => 'xxx',
      'password' => 'xxx',
      'port' => '1521',
      'user' => 'xxx',
    ],
  ],
  'TableMapping' => [
    'SCHEMA.TABLE1' => 'MyDB'
  ],
  'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
],
```

I use QueryBuilder in the action in my controller and I can query the table without any problems.

**BUT** installing **any** extension in ExtensionManager leads to the following error:

```
(1/1) TypeError
Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener::getDatabaseType() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\inetpub\typo3_src-9.5.7\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener.php on line 41
in C:\inetpub\typo3_src-9.5.7\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener.php line 93
*
* @param string $typeDefiniton
* @return string
*/
protected function getDatabaseType(string $typeDefiniton): string
{
$dbType = strtolower($typeDefiniton);
$dbType = strtok($dbType, '(), ');
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener->getDatabaseType(null)
in C:\inetpub\typo3_src-9.5.7\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener.php line 41
public function onSchemaColumnDefinition(SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs $event)
{
$tableColumn = $event->getTableColumn();
$tableColumn = array_change_key_case($tableColumn, CASE_LOWER);
$dbType = $this->getDatabaseType($tableColumn['type']);
if ($dbType !== 'enum' && $dbType !== 'set') {
return;
}
at TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\EventListener\SchemaColumnDefinitionListener->onSchemaColumnDefinition(object(Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs))
```

As soon as I remove the second database from LocalConfiguration.php the ExtensionManager is working again - but of course the QueryBuilder does not know the table any more :enttäuscht:

Comment: Can you tell us how you create the QueryBuilder?

Comment: yes of course, but I don't think there is any problem there:
1) the error occurs even if the extension which uses the querybuilder is not installed - as I wrote the error occurs with ANY extension I want to install after the entry in LocalConfiguration.php
2) the QueryBuilder works :-)
that's how I use it:
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('SCHEMA.TABLE1');
        $result = $queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->from('SCHEMA.TABLE1')
            ->execute();
        $rows = $result->fetchAll();